# Android Studio 3 - Can't run app after install APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-studio-3.0

When I build a debug APK to install it on a device, the installer says the app is installed but it won't let me open the app when it's done. It also hasn't made a shortcut of the app, I can only see/remove it under Settings.

I'm developingt the project in **Android Studio 3.0 Canary 9**.
I started developing this project in Android Studio 2.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Please ask if you need more details.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Android Studio instead of a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

My intent-filters were wrong in my AndroidManifest.xml.

I had to separate these to filters from the rest to fix it:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```